# Best way of storing records and then iterating through them?

Tags: python

Old habits being what they are, I would declare global variables, and probably use lists to store records. I appreciate this is not the best way of doing this these days, and that Python actively discourages you from doing this by having to constantly declare 'global' throughout.

So what should I be doing? I'm thinking I should maybe use instances, but I know of no way to create a unique instance name based on an identifier (all the records will have a unique ID) and then find out how many instances I have.

I could use dictionaries maybe?

The most important thing is that the values are accessible anywhere in my code, and that I can list the number of records and easily refer to / change the values.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell, without a bit more information about the problem that you are trying to solve, the scope of your code, and your code's architecture.

Generally speaking:

If you're writing a script that's reasonably small in scope, there really is nothing wrong with declaring variables in the global namespace of the script.

If you're writing a larger system - something that goes beyond one module or file, but is not running in a multi-process/multi-thread environment, then you can create a module (as a separate file) that handles storage of your re-used data.  Anytime you need to read or write that data you can import that module.  The module could just expose simple variables, or it can wrap the data in classes and expose methods for creation/reading/updating/deletion.

If you are running in a multi-process/multi-thread environment, then any sort of global in-memory variable storage is going to be problematic.  You'll need to use an external store of some sort - Redis or the like for temporary storage, or a database of some sort for permanent storage.

Comment: I've got couple of threads, nothing massive. I guess it was just starting to look messy with all the globals in every function. I found myself wishing there was a way to declare global once only, that's when I started thinking I was doing it wrong ;)

Comment: It sounds like you may be using the `global` keyword more than you need to.  Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python and https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules